# Function not activating upon onclick event

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this script function but for some reason, it does not activate when i call the function on the onclick event on a button.

I want a javscript alert to pop up when i hit the submit button if either the first name text box or the last name text box has anything in there besides letters.

```
function CheckName(){

var NAME1 = getElementByID('FirstName').value;

var NAME2 = getElementByID('LastName').value;
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

if (NAME1.match(letters) && NAME2.match(letters)) 
{
alert('Your Details have been accepted.')
return true;
}
else
{
alert('Please input alphanumeric characters only'); 
return false; 
}
}
```

Below is the html:

```
<body>

<h1>WELCOME TO PATRICK'S INPUT TEST WEBSITE</h1>
<p>Please Insert your details here.</p>
<form name = "myForm" action="#">

First Name: <br/ >
<input type="text" id="FirstName">
</br/ >
Last Name: <br />
<input type="text" id="LastName"> <br />
<button type = "submit"  onclick= "CheckName()"">Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: where are html Code ?

Comment: You have tons of typos. Please consult the docs.

Answer (score 0):

use this html for your form

```
<form name = "myForm" action="#">
   First Name: <br/ >
   <input type="text" id="FirstName">
   <br/ >
   Last Name: <br />
   <input type="text" id="LastName"> <br />
   <button type = "submit" onclick="CheckName()">Submit </button>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

this works, try it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles.css">
<title>Patrick's Downtime Website</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>WELCOME TO PATRICK'S INPUT TEST WEBSITE</h1>
    <p>Please Insert your details here.</p>
    <form name = "myForm" action="#">
       First Name: <br/ > 
       <input type="text" id="FirstName">
       <br/ > <br />
       Last Name: <br />
       <input type="text" id="LastName"> <br /> <br />
       <button type = "submit" onclick="CheckName()">Submit </button>
    </form>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

    function CheckName(){
        console.log(document);
        var NAME1 = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
        var NAME2 = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        if (NAME1.match(letters) && NAME2.match(letters)) {
            alert('Your Details have been accepted.')
        } else {
            alert('Please input alphanumeric characters only');   
        }
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I tried replacing with your html section instead of mine. Still no Javascript response

Comment: Can you share your complete HTML and js?

Comment: Did you link the js file into the HTML?

Comment: I dont use an external js file... i've set up the function as above at the top of the page which is found under <script> </script> tags

Comment: my full html file is as follows:

Comment: Ok, share your complete file

Comment: it is the answer i added just now

Comment: @PatrickJaramillo, I updated my answer, please try it, it works for me

Comment: hahahahah thanks mate.. rookie mistake on my end. i didn't add "document." on my variable declarations which i only figure out after look at your answer

Comment: Good to hear it works :) than, @PatrickJaramillo upvote and accept my answer if it gave a solution to your question, this way a user that may have your issue will find it also useful :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, `var NAME1 = getElementByID('FirstName').value;` this is incorrect.
Function `GetElementByID` is a part of `document` and should be accessed using `document.`. Also, function's actual name is `getElementById`. So your line should be

`var NAME1 = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;`

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mtk9ofj/)

---

Second, if you wish to validate using regex, you should use `.test` function.

[Sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mtk9ofj/1/)

Few pointers,

- Variable name with all caps is a convention for global variables. You should use lowercase. or camel-case variable names.
- You can separate out validation logic to another function. This will allow you to put only submission related logic in `Submit` function.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mtk9ofj/3/)

#### Reference

- [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)